# Two's complement and fmt.Printf

Tags: go

So computers use Two's complement to internally represent signed integers. I.e., -5 is represented as ^5 + 1 = "1111 1011".

However, trying to print the binary representation, e.g. the following code:

```
var i int8 = -5
fmt.Printf("%b", i)
```

Outputs `-101`. Not quite what I'd expect. Is the formatting different or is it not using Two's complement after all?

Interestingly, converting to an unsigned int results in the "correct" bit pattern:

```
var u uint8 = uint(i)
fmt.Printf("%b", u)
```

Output is `11111011` - exactly the 2s complement of `-5`.

So it seems to me the value is internally the really using Two's complement, but the formatting is printing the unsigned `5` and prepending a `-`.

Can somebody clarify this?

Comment: I am not sure why anyone considers this "weird." No matter what number base you use, a negative number is still negative. If you asked for it in base 8, 12 or 16 I'd expect the same thing.

Comment: Well, I didn't say weird. I was just trying to understand 2s complement and the results were not what I was expecting.

Comment: I don't think you can really hope to understand 2's complement by playing with a number formatting function written in a high-level language.

Comment: What do you suggest instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the answer lies in how the `fmt` module formats binary numbers, rather than the internal format.

If you take a look at [`fmt.integer`](https://golang.org/src/fmt/format.go#L157), one of the very first actions that the function does is to convert the negative signed integer to a positive one:

```
   165      negative := signedness == signed && a < 0
   166      if negative {
   167          a = -a
   168      }
```

There's then logic to append `-` in front of the string that's output [here](https://golang.org/src/fmt/format.go#L273).

IOW `-101` really is `-` appended to `5` in binary.

Note: `fmt.integer` is called from `pp.fmtInt64` in [print.go](https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go), itself called from `pp.printArg` in the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method without using `unsafe`:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "math/bits"
)

func unsigned8(x uint8) []byte {
   b := make([]byte, 8)
   for i := range b {
      if bits.LeadingZeros8(x) == 0 {
         b[i] = 1
      }
      x = bits.RotateLeft8(x, 1)
   }
   return b
}

func signed8(x int8) []byte {
   return unsigned8(uint8(x))
}

func main() {
   b := signed8(-5)
   fmt.Println(b) // [1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1]
}
```

In this case you could also use `[8]byte`, but the above is better if you have
a positive integer, and want to trim the leading zeros.

https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits#RotateLeft

Comment: Some things are best kept to yourself, but other things like this you should just pretend never existed

Answer (score -1):

Unsafe pointers must be used to correctly represent negative numbers in binary format.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "unsafe"
)

func bInt8(n int8) string {
    return strconv.FormatUint(uint64(*(*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(&n))), 2)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(bInt8(-5))
}
```

Output

```
11111011
```