# Big number to HEX in golang

Tags: go, hex, bignum

I'm trying to convert big numbers (`big.Int` or even better `big.Rat`) to hex values.

I'm always having issue converting number when they are negative 0xff..xx or Fixed numbers.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `big.Int` has a `Text()` function that converts the number to a string in a given base. To create a hex string, use `value.Text(16)`. Will that do what you want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure what kind of issues are you having, but big.Int, big.Float and big.Rat implement the `fmt.Formatter` interface, you can use the printf family with the **%x** **%X** to convert to hexadecimal string representation, example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func toHexInt(n *big.Int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", n) // or %x or upper case
}

func toHexRat(n *big.Rat) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", n) // or %x or upper case
}

func main() {
    a := big.NewInt(-59)
    b := big.NewInt(59)

    fmt.Printf("negative int lower case: %x\n", a)
    fmt.Printf("negative int upper case: %X\n", a) // %X for upper case

    fmt.Println("using Int function:", toHexInt(b))

    f := big.NewRat(3, 4) // fraction: 3/4

    fmt.Printf("rational lower case: %x\n", f)
    fmt.Printf("rational lower case: %X\n", f)

    fmt.Println("using Rat function:", toHexRat(f))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BVh7wAYfbF

Comment: well for example shouldn't -54 be FFFFFFFFFFFFFFCA or FFCA instead of  -34 ? maybe something i didn't get

Comment: not sure where did you get that representation, at least what I know for all the languages in the **C** family is they sacrifice the first bit to represent the sign, that's why we have unsigned ints vs. ints, but if you want to know the internals you may check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582550/golang-twos-complement-and-fmt-printf) Also in this case we're referring to big numbers and internally they're stored in a slice or list 'cause they don't fit in a regular register, so not sure how useful may be having the internal representation of that array

Comment: -54 (base 10) would be -36 (base 16) . FFCA would be the twos complement representation.  Many objects like big.Int like to keep the details of how they store data a secret.  Not because they don't want to share but they want to be able to change the implementation without breaking their users code.

Comment: That method will strip leading whitespace. So `0x0ABC` will get you the hex string `abc`. That may not be what you want.